# SVN / Jenkins instances issue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am having code placed at SVN , have two instances of jenkins with two different pom.xml, When both the builds are scheduled simultaneously. One build will pass other will fail mentionign certin classes are not available , but those classes are available.

below is the exception

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) on project perfecto: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are they using separate working directory? If not do you kick clean phase?